# Help id mushroom found in West Midlands, Egland

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I found this mushroom yesterday. It looks like an oyster but it grows in some poorly kept lawn. I am sure there was no tree there in the past. This spot was landscaped a couple of years ago after building some blocks of flats. I turned it over, hoping to find some piece of wood, but there was nothing. It has a mild mushroomy smell. Do you have any ideas what it may be?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They look like pleurotus, i'd ask a mycology specialized forum like reddit or facebook mycology.

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/shentsonebirder/8284582392 unsure